# NPOI setting background color isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I need to set and remove the background color of rows. Somewhy when I set style to the row it isn't working - there is still no background color of the row. I've tried to set the CellStyle property of the single cell and use the HSSFStyle. The result is the same - no background color. Here's the code:

```
        XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle)_myBook.CreateCellStyle();
        // Define cell style according to input color parameter
        XSSFColor colorToFill;
        switch (color)
        {
            default:
                colorToFill = new XSSFColor(Color.Gray);
                break;
        }
        style.SetFillBackgroundColor(colorToFill);
        for (int i = From; i <= To; i++)
        {
            var row = GetCreateRow(i);
            row.RowStyle = style;
        }
```

P.S. Document is opened in XSSF format

Answer (score 36):

Ah, we each had part of the answer! (Casting to XSSFCellStyle was what I was missing, because the ICellStyle doesn't have The SetFill methods so I couldn't get a custom color, only one of the indexed ones...)

There are two things you need to do:

1. Call SetFillForegroundColor, not SetFillBackgroundColor.
2. Set style.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;

Apparently, fills in Excel are two-color, so when you want to change the fill, you HAVE to set a pattern, because the default is a cell with no fill and that means no FillPattern.  SolidForeground is the basic fill pattern, and that means you have to set the foreground color of the fill, not the background color of the fill.  A little counter-intuitive, but "Fill" is referring to "background color of the cell", so you could think of it like "SetBackgroundForegroundColor"/"SetBackgroundBackgroundColor"

Comment: seems like you're meant to be..for that problem :D

Comment: So far, this is the best explanation I've seen for why setting the background color uses a method titled "SetFillForegroundColor". It finally makes sense!

Comment: Simple and effective, yet finding such thing alone was going to cost several hours and/or hairs. Thanks!

Comment: Trying this i encountered an other problem: If you want to apply this style to a row then every cell is colored except the cells with text.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("xxxxxxx")
conn.Open()

Dim a As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(XXXXXX, conn)
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
a.Fill(dt)
conn.Close()
conn.Dispose()

Using fs = New FileStream("C:\123.xlsx", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)

            Dim workbook As IWorkbook = New XSSFWorkbook()
            Dim excelSheet As ISheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1")
            Dim columns As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

            Dim styleOrange As ICellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle    
            Dim row As IRow = excelSheet.CreateRow(0)    
            Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
```

> Blockquote
> For column header

```
            For Each column As Data.DataColumn In dt.Columns
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName)
                row.CreateCell(columnIndex).SetCellValue(column.ColumnName)
                columnIndex += 1
            Next
```

> Blockquote 'for Record and rows to fill excel

```
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = 1    
            For Each dsrow In dt.Rows

                row = excelSheet.CreateRow(rowIndex)    
                Dim cellIndex As Integer = 0 

                For Each col In columns    
                    Dim cell = row.CreateCell(cellIndex)
                    cell.SetCellValue(dsrow(col).ToString())    
               
                    styleOrange.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground
                    styleOrange.FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.Red.Index

                    cell.CellStyle = styleOrange
                    cellIndex += 1

                Next

                rowIndex += 1
            Next              

            workbook.Write(fs)
        End Using
```